# What is a $k$-algebra, what is a $k$-algebra morphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, algebras

Another question on algebras. My question is, can anyone explain what a $k$-algebra is and what a $k$-algebra morphism is to me as if I'm a dummy? What is the intuition for working with them?

Comment: Have you tried looking at for example the definition to get started? Are you familiar with rings?

Comment: Informally It is a $k$-vectorspace with an additional product among the vectors. A good example to keep in mind are square matrices of a fixed dimension.